# what‘s the differences between initializing an array of objects and initializing an object?

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

for example:

`Student[] stu = new Student[10];`

`Student stu = new Student();`
what's the differences between them?

and what happened when initializing an array of objects? why doesn't it call the constructor?

Comment: What do you mean by `Structure function`? Are you referring to the constructor?

Comment: `stu = new Student();` will not work if `stu` is the array of `Student` you just declared the line before. If it's not, you should really choose another name.

Comment: [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) the Java tutorial on Arrays.

Comment: @PakkuDon thanks,i'm not from English-speaking country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `Student.java`:

```
public class Student
{
    private String name;

    public Student () { name = ""; }

    public String getName () { return name; }

    public void setName (String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

Then we have:

```
    Student[] A = null;
```

- `A` is a reference of type `Student[]` which means Array of Student references
- A reference is a memory address
- `A` has `null` value; meaning it refers to nothing

  ```
  Student[] B = new Student[10];
  ```
- `B` is a reference of type `Student[]`
- `new Student[10];` will reserve a memory of 10 memory references of type `Student`
- `B` takes the reference returned by `new` which reference the 10 blocks of `Student` references
- All of the reference blocks reserved by `new` are initialized to `null`
- Attempting `B[0].getName();` will compile, but will throw a `NullPointerException` on run-time

  ```
  B[0] = new Student();
  ```
- `B[0]` is the first element in the array `B` initially refers to `null`
- `new Student();` will create an Object of type `Student` by invoking its constructor `Student()` known as the default constructor
- After this, you can call Student functions like `B[0].getName();`

  ```
  Student C = null;
  ```
- `C` is a reference of type `Student`
- `C` has the value of `null` which means it refers to nothing
- Attempting `C.getName();` will compile, but will throw a `NullPointerException` on run-time

  ```
  C = new Student();
  ```
- `C` will take the reference returned by `new Student();`
- `new Student();` will create an object of type `Student` by calling its constructor `Student()` and return its memory reference

Answer (score 2):

Initializing an array creates *empty spaces* for each element. It does not create any individual element. This

```
Student[] stus = new Student[10];
```

therefore creates ten empty spaces, into each of which can be placed a `Student` object. No other kind--unless it sub-classes `Student`. Each of these ten spaces are `null` until you explicitely place a new object into them. Such as with

```
stus[1] = new Student();  //1 is the *second* element
```

Initializing an object creates a new object of that type. This

```
Student stu = new Student();
```

creates a new `Student` object. Alternatively, this

```
Student stu;
```

*declares* the object, but does not create it. It's just like when you initialize the array. This allots a space for the (one) `Student` object, but does not create it.

To repeat, this creates (initializes) it--meaning *places it in that declared space*:

```
stu = new Student();
```

As a final note, as mentioned by @FlorentBayle, you should not name these objects the same. Consider naming the array as I do above: `stus`, which is more indicative of its actual value.

More information:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=initialize+values+in+array+java
- https://www.google.com/search?q=declare+array+java
- https://www.google.com/search?q=declare+vs+initialize+java

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize an array, all the elements are null, initially. When you make a `Student` object, it actually calls the `Student` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In the array instantiation/initialization you are allocating enough memory to hold 10 Student objects. In your instantiation/initialization of stu, Your stu variable refers to one Student object in memory

Answer (score 0):

I agree with PakkuDon, don't know what you mean by "`Structure Function`."

Initializing an array of objects will make a new array of `Student` objects, which is basically a list of size `Student[x]` where `x` is the number of objects in the array.
When you actually add a `Student` object to the array, it will call the `Student` constructor, and create the `Student` object.

Simply creating a `Student` object will actually create the object, not just a list that can hold them.

Answer (score 0):

in `Student[] stu = new Student[10];` you initialize an array of 10 elements that take up 10xsize of the `Student` object. But with `stu = new Student();` it takes up only 1xsize of the `Student` object.

Answer (score 0):

`Student[] stu = new Student[10];` creates an an array that can hold 10 Student objects. Each element is initialised to null.

`Student stu = new Student();` creates a single Student.

As for your question on why the constructor isn't called when constructing an array of objects, I'd ask "Why would it be?" The compiler only knows that the array can store objects that are an instance of Student. How is the compiler supposed to know which constructor it is supposed to call to construct these objects? What should the compiler do in the event that your class, Student, lacks a no-args constructor?

There's also the fact that the programmer may wish to populate the array with data retrieved from an external source during runtime. It would make more sense to default to `null` rather than to populate the array with a bunch of arbitrary instances that are going to be discarded later since that'll add an unnecessary overhead to the program.